# $ H $ hilbert space: Hamel dimension of $ H $ = Hilbert dimension of $ H $ $ \Leftrightarrow$ dim $ H $ is finite

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Clearly $\Leftarrow $ is a trivial trivial application of G-Schmidt algorithm.  I've experienced some trouble in proving the other direction. I focused my self on the fact that span($ A $)=$ H $ (it can be not closed) where A is an Hamel base, but i i didn't found nothing. I can't even use G-S because the cardinality of the hamel base can be uncountable.  Clearly the interesting case (where to find an absurd) is when H has an uncountable hilbert dimension.

Someone has some advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's wrong. If $H$ has a hilbert basis of cardinality $\kappa \geqslant 2^{\aleph_0}$, I think its cardinality is $\kappa$, and that means (since $\kappa \geqslant \operatorname{card}\mathbb{C}$) that its Hamel bases have cardinality $\kappa$. I'm not 100% sure that $\kappa \geqslant \operatorname{card}\mathbb{C}$ implies Hilbert dimension = cardinality, though. But almost.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't see why having cardinality larger than the continuum implies that. I could believe that there is a Hilbert space with a topological basis of size $\aleph_\omega$, but its closure - and the Hamel basis cardinality is $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ (e.g. if you assume $(\aleph_\omega)^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, okay. Then $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$ holds only for some $\kappa$. Still, these are counterexamples.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would you care to check the cardinal arithmetic in my answer? I'm almost sure it's right, but I'd like to have an expert check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces whose Hamel-dimension equals the Hilbert-dimension.

Remember that every Hilbert space is (isometrically isomorphic to) $\ell^2(\kappa)$ for some cardinal $\kappa$.

Let $\kappa = 2^{\aleph_\alpha}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$. Then $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\max\{\aleph_\alpha,\aleph_0\}} = 2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \kappa$. Letting $\iota_S \colon \ell^2(S) \to \ell^2(\kappa)$ the canonical inclusion for a subset $S\subset \kappa$, we have

$$\ell^2(\kappa) = \bigcup_{\substack{S\subset\kappa\\ \lvert S\rvert \leqslant \aleph_0}} \iota_S(\ell^2(S)).$$

Since every $\ell^2(S)$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ (or $1$, if $S$ is empty), and there are no more than $\kappa$ countable subsets of $\kappa$, we have

$$\operatorname{card} \ell^2(\kappa) \leqslant \kappa \otimes \mathfrak{c} = \max \{\kappa,\mathfrak{c}\} = \kappa.$$

On the other hand, the cardinality is trivially at least $\kappa$, so we have equality.

The same argument for finite subsets of a basis shows that $\dim_{\text{Hamel}} V = \operatorname{card} V$ for a (real or complex) vector space $V$ if the dimension is at least $\mathfrak{c}$.

So we have $\dim_{\text{Hamel}} \ell^2(2^{\aleph_\alpha}) = \operatorname{card} \ell^2(2^{\aleph_\alpha}) = \dim_{\text{Hilbert}} \ell^2(2^{\aleph_\alpha})$ for all ordinals $\alpha$.

Comment: Unless I screwed up the cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: Urgh, have you some references fpr your first "remember"? Never seen or heard of it :(

Comment: @RicPed [As a consequence of Parseval's identity, if $\{e_k\}_{k \in B}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$, then the map $\Phi : H \to  \ell^2(B)$ defined by $\Phi(x) = (\langle x,e_k\rangle)_{k\in B}$ is an isometric isomorphism of Hilbert spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Hilbert_dimension)

Comment: Tha fact that i can view $\ell^2 (B) $ as an union of $ \ell ^2 (A) $ where A is at most countable is a consequence of parseval identity?  Sorry for answering later but it took time to understand the answer:)

Comment: The Parseval identity plus the fact that a summable family of real numbers can have at most countably many nonzero elements. The elements of the summable family of real numbers are the squares of the moduli of the Fourier-coefficients, $\lvert\langle x,e_k\rangle\rvert^2$. So every $x\in H$ is a "linear combination" of a countable subset $S$ of the Hilbert basis, hence a member of $\ell^2(S)$.